# Code section in markdown behaving differently

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering

In my answer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094692/parse-error-when-run-by-cron-but-not-from-command-line/2094722#2094722), I am using the code tag to outline two lines.

```
$temp = $t->course(); 
$courses[$t->CourseNumber] = $temp->CourseName;
```

the code looks fine in the preview, but in the final version, the second line is not rendered as code.
Why? Is this valid behaviour?

Edit: I see now that this happens only when the line of code is the last element in the text, which makes it less dramatic. Still, is this a bug?

Comment: I guess moving the example to the end helps making your point ;-) (I know, the linked answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094692/parse-error-when-run-by-cron-but-not-from-command-line/2094722#2094722 shows what you mean, but that might be fixed by someone, some day?)

Comment: True! But Jeff sneakily fixed the bug already, so the point is moot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have an unprintable character interfering with the layout (unicode or ASCII). When I type it in manually, it works fine.

Edit:

Now I see -- this a bug in `Normalize()` where an empty (spaces, then newline) line at the end was not being removed. Unfortunately this routine was contributed code, so I rewrote it.

fixed in:

http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=111